# Почему функция выполняется один раз если она в цикле? C++ Arduino

Tags: c++, циклы, arduino, while

Пишу многопоточность для Arduino, а для этого надо убрать все `delay();`. Я заменяю эти делаи на `millis();`, но это всё работает только один раз, хотя цикл - задержка правильная, но она срабатывает один раз. Почему так?

Вот код:

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000;

int main() {

  //init();

  while (1) {
    led13_ne();
  }

}

void led13_ne() {
  DDRB |= B10000000;
  init();
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  byte port13read = 0;

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    port13read = bitRead(PORTB, 8);

    if (port13read == 0) {
      PORTB |= B10000000;
      //port13read = 1;
    } else {
      PORTB &= ~B10000000;
      //port13read = 0;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `init();` в цикле **зачем**?

Comment: `bitRead(PORTB, 8);` — как ты девятый бит из байта читаешь?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, [https://pp.userapi.com/c846019/v846019647/c75d/7Xt_GThn-tM.jpg](https://pp.userapi.com/c846019/v846019647/c75d/7Xt_GThn-tM.jpg) _Тыц_

Comment: @Fat-Zer `init();` для `millis();`.

Comment: спрошу по-другому, зачем `init ()` **в цикле**? и `bitRead(PORTB, 8);` — пытается вернуть **девятый** бит из восьмибитного значения, понятно, что он всегда будет нулевой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я, что, накосячил? Может выложите рабочий код?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75348/discussion-between-timoha-timohavich-and-fat-zer).

Comment: Могу посоветовать мою статью https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/arduino-kak-migat-svetodiodom-bez-delay

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics 1) Пхаха, гугл сайты... На гитхабе хотяб захостил. 2) Это копипаст примера из Arduino IDE. Я же делаю всё на голых PORTB. Вот код для тебя (вообще он для всех): https://hastebin.com/kamizapomu.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bitRead ()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitread/) возвращает значение i-го бита переданного ему байта считая с **нуля**. Поэтому что бы получить значение старшего бита надо выполнить:

```
bitRead(PORTB, 7);
```

Кроме того, эта запись в точности аналогична:

```
(PORTB >> 7) & 0x01;
```

Которой я и рекомендовал бы пользоваться, раз уж наметился курс на отказ от излишеств arduino. т.о. Аналогичная конструкция для 8-ки всегда будет возвращать ноль.

Кроме того `init ()` должна быть вызвана один раз т.е. стоит раскомментировать её в `main ()` и убрать из `led13_ne ()`. В данном случае не так критично, но в принципе — это плохая практика.

Comment: Я, собственно, в первый раз посмотрел на Arduino, [и вот тут](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) про PORTB пишут -- `PORTB maps to Arduino digital pins 8 to 13 The two high bits (6 & 7) map to the crystal pins and are not usable`. Вы уверены, что тут вообще имеет смысл говорить о 7-м бите?

Comment: @avp, cкорей всего у него Mega — там седьмой бит PORTB на встроенный светодиод [идёт](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf?)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ага, вы угадали, я мучаю Мегу))